# Unsubscribe Token for Subscription Reminders

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

What's the best way to allow members to unsubscribe or opt out from Renewal Reminders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there's not a way to opt-out of transactional emails, like receipts and reminders.

I found [this](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/email/scheduled-reminders/) in the documentation, which states

> Scheduled reminders are still sent to contacts who have opted out of
>   bulk emails and those who have selected the privacy option Do not
>   email.

It goes on to say

> If you want to exclude contacts who have opted out of bulk emails from
>   a scheduled reminder you should:
>
> 1) Find all contacts who have not
>   selected the privacy options Do not email or NO BULK EMAIL.
>
> 2) Create
>   a smart group from the search results.
>
> 3) Select this smart group as
>   the Recipients of the scheduled reminder.

Comment: How would you craft a 'opt-out' link to work in this scenario ?

Comment: I'd have to test it, but I think a regular "opt out" link would work.  Another alternative would be to create a profile called "Communication Preferences" and put the User Opt Out field, and maybe some of the other communications preferences fields and add a link to the profile using the contact hash.